# Bulk update tags in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, tags, tagging

I am looking out for a way to update all my tags(both key and value) with EC2 and other resources. 
I tried aws-tagger and its helpful in updating the tag values. But I need update in the Tag Key as well.

I want to make all my tags(CAPITAL Letters) to SMALL Letters.(this is the requirement)

So it needs update in both key and value. Could someone assist on this please.
Looking forward!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since EC2 doesn't have update tag API, your best bet is to iterate over a list of target EC2's, save the values of the tag temporarily in the code, delete the tag, and create a new tag with previously saved values converted to lowercase.

Comment: I tried something else. Deleted all existing tags with tag editor(manual task) and added new tags (lower letters) with aws-tagger. But still this involves lot of manual tasks. So looking for updating rather than delete and add. Thanks

Comment: @John Rotenstein Looking for your help.